# Call next in a separate function

Tags: r

I would like to call next in a function like:

```
fn=function(env=parent.frame())
{
  evalq(next,envir=env)
}

for (i in 1:10)
{
 fn()
}
```

I get this output:

```
#no loop for break/next, jumping to top level
```

And the loop stops.
Any suggestion? Thanks

```
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21) -- "You Stupid Darkness"
```

Comment: This looks like an XY problem. Could you provide more context?

Comment: for reference [xy-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "doesn't work". What did you expect? What did you get? Code is, actually, doing what it is supposed to do. if you put `print("this should get printed")` before `evalq` and `print("this should not get printed")` after, you will see that it is working, as in `next` is being called

Comment: @Jav : Sorry for the lack of detail of my question. I edited it. But I dont think what you write is correct: the loops stops at the first call to fn()

Comment: @nicola and DJJ : I dont know if its a "XY" problem as I would like to understand this particular behaviour and to know whether it is possible to call next in a separate function

Comment: @user3507085 Are you calling the code just like the way you provided here, not within any other function/environment?

Comment: For me, in fresh load of R with above modifications it will return 10 times `[1] "this should get printed"`

Comment: I reproduce OP's error. `R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)  Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)  Running under: Linux Mint 18  Matrix products: default  BLAS: /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/libblas.so.3.0  LAPACK: /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/liblapack.so.3.0  locale:  [1] LC_CTYPE=fr_FR.UTF-8  ...  attached base packages:  [1] stats  graphics  grDevices utils  datasets  methods  base  loaded via a namespace (and not attached):  [1] compiler_3.4.0 tools_3.4.0`

Comment: Ok it might be a pb of R version: it is working with R version 3.3.3 but not it is not with R version 3.4.0 !